# How to extract all text found in a webpage JSoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Does anyone know how I can extract texts beyond`<p> blah blah blah </p>`
 (basically texts found in other elements as well)
`
in a webpage. It has to be a complete chronological order as how it is displayed in the original webapge.

What I meant beyond `<p> tags` would be also to extract words in the heading from `<h1>, <h2>,<h3> and <h4>` too!
So for e.g. given a html webpage

```html
<html> 
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <h2>Heading 2</h2>
    <p>This is a random paragraph</p> 
    <h1>Heading3</h1> 
    <p>This is another random paragraph</p> 
</html>
```

*It gets a bit complication if webpage exist to have  tag after p tags in the main body too.

So the desired (chronological) output would be as shown above!

*Using JSoup! :)

Comment: The html shown is not enclosing the h tags inside p tags. Both are separate elements. So did you meant to say you need to print the value of all tag from one p to another or to print values of child elements of a p tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to learn about [CSS selectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets#Selector), as jsoup uses that syntax and concepts for querying the document.

You need to read the [jsoup doc](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax). That doc even shows an example fitting your snippet.

```
Elements elements = doc.select("p > h1"); // Find a h1 directly following a p.
```

Or more generally:

```
Elements elements = doc.select("h1"); // Find all h1 elements.
```

Then loop the collection of elements. On each element, extract the element's own text content.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend using jQuery to do this.

Use the jQuery [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function to get the text without the html tags.
Use the jQuery [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function to get everything including the html tags.

So extract the text between your html tags you can just do something like:

```
var text = $('html').text();
```